# StreamDensityPlot plots arrows of different length

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I am plotting a vector field with StreamDensityPlot. I know it's symmetric about the $x$ and $y$ axes because of the equation, but also because if I plot it with VectorDensityPlot, it shows the correct "lengths".

I prefer StreamDensityPlot because it has longer arrows and better shows the flow of the field.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Does the `StreamScale` option provide what you need?

Comment: The ending line segment in a streamline almost always won't be the same size as the standard-sized line segments preceding it.  So that can't be fixed.  But if the "tiny" arrows at then end of those ending line segments are annoying (which by default are proportional to the length of the line segment), those can be made the same size as all of the others.  Try something like `StreamScale -> {0.5, 10, 0.02}]` for longer line segments with a constant sized arrowhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide the function you used, so:

```
StreamDensityPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 StreamScale -> {Automatic, 2, Automatic}
```

[image]